Replacing the EPS rack on a Ford Fusion with one from a Toyota Camry to enable autonomous driving
I am doing a project car as an EV conversion and adding autonomy software using Baidu ApolloAuto  open source self driving software.
It will not be my daily driver, just for learning and sunny day drives in the neighborhood.
The donor car is a 2012 Ford Fusion SE. I already took out the engine and transmission.
The Ford Fusion has a power steering rack where the EPS motor is part of the assembly.  I prefer the Toyota style where the power steering motor is separate and attached to the column.
That Toyota EPS is very popular in hot rod rebuilds on YouTube as well. It requires no programming and defaults to 40 MPH handling, but with a few CAN messages, can be set to specific torques used in lane keeping assistance.
Which of course makes it very appealing because it can integrate easily with the self driving software using CAN messages.
The Toyota Camry steering rack is approx the same size.  What are the things I need to watch out for when swapping it in? What are the gotcha's going to be with that?
I am thinking to mount the Toyta EPS to the firewall or subframe and the connect the stock Ford steering column with an adapter/weld.


You'll have to carry out new EMC testing if you modify the vehicle electronics. Very expensive.

Sort the steering geometry - mounting the rack will be the easy part.
Making or sourcing steering rods of the correct length will be the challenge - if you make them then future replacement becomes an issue.

thanks @SolarMike for the answer.  That's a good place to start.

It might be simpler to just take the entire Camry front subframe plus suspension then adapt the bodywork.  This was done quite a bit with Ford stuff, but I've only seen it done within the brand - ie stuffing Mustang front ends under pretty much anything else build on the same pans - Cougars, Fairmonts, Ltd IIs, Zephyrs, etc.
